# Unable to determine why workbook gets marked as read only when opening another workbook via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Background: I can't seem to find an answer for the blunder I've found myself in. I'm working on a dashboard of sorts for our organization that pulls data from different workbooks in different locations. Different people have different permissions within folders in our company. We're trying to prevent having to change permissions. I was also trying to make it easy as possible for employees by moving the necessary supporting files I pull from to my folder where the dashboard is housed that includes a folder with the supporting files. Since this folder has no restricted access, I added passwords to the whole workbook of each supporting file. I created workbooks in the original locations of where these supporting files used to reside with the hopes that would hopefully allow anyone with access in that folder to use this new file as a backdoor/shortcut of sorts. The goal was to keep people's files where they wanted them and allow them to click it then it takes them to my support file and enter the password for them. Which leads me to the problem...

Problem: When I open the "backdoor" file, everything runs normally and the support file opens up with read and write privileges. However when someone else opens the backdoor file, the support file opens as read only. While I don't have any code yet to determine if someone is in the file (I'll cross that road if my problem is resolvable), I've ensured nobody was in the support or backdoor file when another user attempted to use it.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
'I didn't have the next statement orginally. Added it in hopes it'd resolve the issue.
'Tried to move it under the workbooks.open command, too, but to no avail.

SetAttr "M:\Report Writing\Supporting Files\TMR 2017 - Team ABC's SF.xlsm", vbNormal
Workbooks.Open "M:\Report Writing\Supporting Files\TMR 2017 - Team ABC's SF.xlsm", , False, , "XXX"
Workbooks("TMR 2017 - Team ABC's.xlsm").Close

End Sub
```

I also didn't originally have the "False" in the open.workbooks command but tried to add it in hopes of resolving my dilemma. Any hope is GREATLY appreciated as my whole dashboard is relying on this and we were supposed to deploy today.

Comment: Does the user who opened the “backdoor” file actually have permission to edit the files from which you are pulling? If they have readonly access then that permission will follow through as they are the one launching the initial program and it will inherit the user’s permission level.

Comment: Yes, each backdoor file resides where the file used to be, meaning anyone who has access within that folder should have permission to edit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the VBA code. It is the file itself. On a shared network, depending on how it was set up, when a new file is created everyone can read it, but only the creator is marked as the only one allowed to make changes. If someone Saves the file with another name you wont be able to edit it. You created the file, you can make changes to it.

There is a way to change this. Right click on the file, properties, security, Edit Button, There are some listed users in there but just find the one that says Drive\Users or Authenticated Users, or both, and edit that to provide modify access. This will allow everyone to edit the file.

Comment: Ricardo, you made my day. Thank you so much for the solution and explanation. Cheers!